# wrong output in address array after using json_encode() and JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, loops

I have this PHP which is fetching all rows of address column from the database and i an using `json_encode()` function to convert it into string and `JSON.parse` in javascript but i am not getting output as expected

```
 <? 

 include('dbcon.php');
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT address FROM markers");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $new_array[] = $row; 
 }
 print_r($new_array);

 $add_js = json_encode( $new_array );

 print_r($add_js);
 ?>
```

with `print_r($new_array);`  i am getting two dimentional arrary and getting `null` in zeroth location. any changes i make it keeps on giving null at zeroth location.

```
   var address = [JSON.parse( '<?php echo $add_js ?>' )];
```

`var address` should store array of addresses but it is giving output when i alert in the array.

`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

i want to store array of addresses after fetching them from database

Comment: Can you please post the results which your PHP generates?

Comment: First of all initialize the $new_array by adding $new_array = arary() at the begining of you code. Then alert won't display json string, it is an object, rather than using alert() for debuging, add console.log(address); and checkout your browser console (f11).

Comment: What's wrong with that array of objects, what did you expect (`[object Object]` is OK for an object that gets stringified from an alert)? Are you sure that you need the brackets (array literal) around the `JSON.parse` expression? Also, you should not need to use a string and explicit parse, you can simply echo the JSON as a javascript literal into the code.

Comment: results of php are ' Array ( [0] => Array ( [address] => Janak Puri, New Delhi, India ) [1] => Array ( [address] => Sector 63, Noida ) [2] => Array ( [address] => Dwarka, New Delhi, India ) [3] => Array ( [address] => Laxmi Nagar,new delhi ) [4] => Array ( [address] => Gurgaon, Haryana, India ) ) [{"address":"Janak Puri, New Delhi, India"},{"address":"Sector 63, Noida"},{"address":"Dwarka, New Delhi, India"},{"address":"Laxmi Nagar,new delhi"},{"address":"Gurgaon, Haryana, India"}] ' these are results fron temporary database.

Comment: Why are you not just using `var address = <?php echo json_encode($some_variable);?>;`?

Comment: @FilipGórny change after $new_array = arary()

Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( [address] => Janak Puri, New Delhi, India ) [2] => Array ( [address] => Sector 63, Noida ) [3] => Array ( [address] => Dwarka, New Delhi, India ) [4] => Array ( [address] => Laxmi Nagar,new delhi ) [5] => Array ( [address] => Gurgaon, Haryana, India ) )

Comment: @Bergi instead of [object Object] i am expecting addresses. i have used those  brackets (array literal) around the JSON.parse cuz i need array of addresses.

yeah i have now used 

var address = <?php echo json_encode($some_variable);?>;

Comment: @Wrikken thanks for the suggestion. I have now corrected it :)

Comment: @Sonam: Well, you've got objects which all have an `address` property. Change your PHP code to `$new_array[] = $row["address"];` (where you're only adding the strings to the `new_array`) and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `$new_array` is an array of associative arrays, and it is decoded in JavaScript as an array of objects. If you want an array of strings instead, then you need to store strings in `$new_array`:

```
$new_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $new_array[] = $row['address'];   // <-- This line
}

print_r($new_array);

$add_js = json_encode( $new_array );

print_r($add_js);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough for your need:

```
var address = <?php echo $add_js ?>
```